# Extract a list of month names from "mmyyyy" data by user

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with `UserID` and `MonthYear` which is in the following format `12015` for January 2015 or `32014` for March 2014, `122015` for December and so on. Each `UserId` has multiple lines for months.

The query

```
select UserId, MonthYear 
from table1 
order by UserId, MonthYear;
```

returns something like this:

```
x223 12015
x223 32015
x223 82015 
x223 92015
x223 102015
x223 112015
.
.
.
x100 72014
x100 92014
```

I want to create a table/query from table1 that outputs in the following format

```
x223 (February, April, May, June, July, December)
x100 (January, February...December)
```

This is the best I could come up to:

```
select 
    UserId, Months 
from 
    table2 
where 
    Months not in (select left(MonthYear), 1 
                   where len(MonthYear) < 6)  
group by 
    UserID, Months;
```

I am trying to do this in Access but any hint that works in SQL is also very valuable.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.  Also, what do you do about the year?

Comment: I forgot to say that it would be great to insert all those missing months on one cell, basically on one column row that I would call Months.

Comment: . . That is quite complicated in MS Access.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. My guess is to somehow dump the query result in a table and to use multiple queries to somehow step by step get to the desired results. Thank you for at least confirming my fears that it is not trivial despite the straightforward puzzle.

Comment: You should first remove last 4 characters of `monthyear`, to get only months, like `1`,`12` etc. Then you need to use a `decode` or `case` to assign `1` as `January` , `2` as `February` etc. So now you have `userid` and `month` . Then you need to search for an alternative of `group_concat` or `listagg` in `access`. As Gordon says, it is complicated to do in MS Access, but you can give it a try and let us know if you face issue is doing it.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are involved? (What's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a copy of the [ConcatRelated() function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) and a saved query to extract the month numbers from [table1].[MonthYear]. With the saved query named [qryExtractMonthNumbers] ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    UserId,
    Val(Mid(MonthYear,1,Len(MonthYear)-4)) AS intMonth
FROM table1
```

... we can use it as the row source for the `ConcatRelated()` call in the following query ...

```sql
SELECT 
    UserId,
    ConcatRelated("MonthName(intMonth)","qryExtractMonthNumbers","UserId='" & UserId & "'","intMonth") AS MonthNames
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM table1)
```

which returns

```
UserId  MonthNames
------  ----------------------------------------------------
x100    July, September
x223    January, March, August, September, October, November
```

Comment: That worked. Quite amazing how short the queries were too. Thank you!